# How to download an image from a website and save it to the Blob via Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

This code saves the image with a size of 0 bytes. Why doesn't it save the whole image?

Here is an example of how to directly save an image to blob storage.

```
[FunctionName("ImportFunc")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "import/{category}")] HttpRequest req,
        [Blob("images/{category}.jpeg", FileAccess.Write)] 
        Stream image,
        string category,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            // URL of the image to download
            string imageUrl = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg";

            // Create a new HttpClient instance
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            // Download the image as a stream 
            image = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(imageUrl);

            return new OkResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex, "Something went wrong");
            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Initialize the storage conn string blob container defining from `local.settings.json` in the function code and a Memory Stream blob object which is used to read the file that you are uploading.

Comment: ```string StorageConnString = Environment.GetEnvironmentvariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
string blobContainer = Environment.GetEnvironmentvariable("Name_of_the_Container");

Stream blobToUpload = new MemoryStream();
//Read the File you want to upload using file.OpenReadString();
var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(StorageConnString, blobContainer);
var blobToUpload = blobClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
await blobToUpload.UploadAsync(myBlob);
```